# using metasploit framework in docker

Tags: docker, ubuntu, docker-machine

To use metasploit framework in docker i should use this command:

> docker pull metasploitframework/metasploit-framework

and for using ubuntu in docker i should use this command:

> docker pull ubuntu

I have a question: If i want to use metasploit framework in docker that is installed in windows should i first install ubuntu in `docker` and then install `metasploit` inside ubuntu or can i use metasploit framwork in docker without installing `ubuntu`?

Answer (score 1):

No, just pulling **metasploitframework/metasploit-framework** image should be enough.

Both commands should work the same on Windows if you are using Docker Engine.

Behind the scenes, Docker Engine creates a Linux virtual machine running docker.

Answer (score 1):

To use Metasploit Framework in Docker on a Windows host, you do not need to install Ubuntu separately. The Metasploit Framework Docker image is already built on top of a Linux distribution (Alpine Linux), which provides the necessary environment to run Metasploit.

1. Pull the Metasploit Framework Docker image: Use the following
   command to pull the Metasploit Framework image from Docker Hub

   `docker pull metasploitframework/metasploit-framework`
2. Run Metasploit Framework container: Once the image is pulled, you
   can run a container using the following command:

   `docker run --rm -it metasploitframework/metasploit-framework`

This command will start a new Docker container with the Metasploit Framework and provide you with an interactive shell inside the container, where you can use Metasploit commands.